# scrapy scrape only after checking if a class exits

Tags: python, scrapy

I've created a crawler to crawl a webpage and store items in mysql database. I'm facing a slight problem while scraping a fixed part of the webpage. I want to check if a div with certain class name exits inside a div or not and if it exits, i will store the root div.

```
<div class="page-col-1-2-right">
 <div class="block">
  <h2>Produktbewertung und Test</h2>
  <div class="area spacing ingredient-rating"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="block">
  <h2>Artikel zu Nasentropfen & Schnupfen</h2>
  <div class="cell clickable teaser-large" data-id="62151"></div>
 <div>
</div>
```

In the above code, i want div block if and only if it has

```
<div class="area spacing ingredient-rating"></div>
```

inside it. Since some pages of the website i'm crawling might have or might not have the required block my code below didn't work.

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "page-col-1-2-right")]/div[contains(@class, "block")][2]').extract()[0]
```

Comment: does it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you a test to perform before extracting the text you can make usage of a `and` expression inside the xpath. So it will be `response.xpath(test1 and test2).extract()[0]`

Applying it to your code it:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "page-col-1-2-right")]/div[contains(@class, "block")][2]' and '//div[contains(@class, "ingredient-rating")]').extract()[0]`
```